# Search Engine implementation for relational database like Oracle DB

Tags: java, oracle, elasticsearch, spring-data, hibernate-search

I have a requirement to create a search engine for relational database like Oracle. I have to create a search engine with the help of Elastic Search. After a week of analysis still am not sure; what kind of architecture should i follow for this requirement.

```
Spring boot-spring data-elasticsearch
Spring data-elasticsearch
Spring boot-hibernatesearch
```

After this I have gone throught this site to make some idea about hibernate search.

http://hibernate.org/search/releases/5.9/

Still am not very clear which one i have to follow to implement the search engine for relational database. Any suggestions.?

Search Engine that am referring like a search component as attached.

[image]

Comment: Your question, in its current form, is probably too broad.  But take a step back; can you tell us what this search engine is supposed to be doing?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I have a webapplication with global search component. so, from that search component if i start entering any key it should give me some suggestions based on the key entered. And that data is coming from Oracle database. its more or less like a google/yahoo search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is about whether to use Spring-Data or Hibernate Search, then you might want to have a look at [my answer to this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47918507/hibernate-search-vs-spring-data-solr-spring-data-elasticsearch/47920881#47920881).

Quoting:

> I'm obviously biased since I am a Hibernate developer, but I can at
>   least provide some elements focused on Hibernate Search. As to which
>   is "better", that's for you to judge.
>
> The main difference is that Hibernate Search provides integration
>   between JPA and your index of choice (Lucene or Elasticsearch):
>
> - Hibernate Search will automatically add/update/delete documents in your full-text index according to changes in your JPA entities (as
>     soon as you commit a transaction).
> - Hibernate Search will allow your to build a full-text query (full-text world), and retrieve the results as managed entities (JPA
>     world).
>
> As far as I understand, Spring-Data-Elasticsearch is focused on
>   accessing Elasticsearch and has no JPA integration whatsoever. That is
>   to say, you can use Spring-Data-JPA, and you can use
>   Spring-Data-Elasticsearch, but they won't communicate with each other.
>   You will have two separate models, which you will update and query
>   separately.
>
> Some other elements:
>
> - If you don't need a distributed index, Hibernate Search can run in embedded Lucene mode, without all the Elasticsearch stack. It will
>     probably be more lightweight.
> - Hibernate Search is *currently* not very flexible when it comes to customizing your Elasticsearch mapping or using advanced Elasticsearch
>     features, because of the abstraction layer. That will change in the
>     future, though ([Hibernate Search 6](http://hibernate.org/search/roadmap/#hibernate-search-6-x)).
> - A Spring-Data-HibernateSearch module is in the works, allowing to benefit from the best of both worlds. It hasn't been released yet and
>     is not really well documented yet, though:
>     https://github.com/snowdrop/spring-boot-hibernate-search-booster