# Can I use Spring Data ElasticSearch instead of Specification for MySQL query?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I want to build a `/search` endpoint, I find Specification quite hard to code and limiting if traverse across multiple microservices.

Is using Spring Data ElasticSearch instead for MySQL search a good option?

Comment: I maybe confused as to your question, but the two are not comparable....  Searching MYSQL Database is different than searching an Elastic Search Index...

You cant use Spring Data ElasticSerach to search MySQL Database....

Comment: @JCompetence There are a lot of tutorials like [this](https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-elasticsearch/) that uses Elasticsearch for product query and things like that. So I image those products are in some sort of DB like MySQL?

Comment: Two different things.   If you have products, that you will be adding, deleting, updating, then you need a database.


Depending on how huge your data is, you might not need an ElasticSearch instance.

If your data is huge, and you are noticing that basic JPA is slow, then perhaps look into Hibernate Search which also uses Elastic Search.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47918507/hibernate-search-vs-spring-data-solr-spring-data-elasticsearch

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Elastic search has many options for searching items like:

- Query DSL. Query DSL supports a variety of query types you can mix
  and match to get the results you want
- Aggregations
- Search multiple data streams and indices
- Paginate search results
- Retrieve selected fields
- Sort search results
- Run an async search